Tailwind CSS Utility Classes Not Recognized in Next.js 14 Until Rebuild
I'm using Next.js 14 with Tailwind CSS in my project. I've noticed that Tailwind CSS utility classes are not always recognized immediately when I add them.
To see the new utility classes in action, I have to stop the development server, delete the .next build folder, and then restart the server.
Here's an example of the issue I'm facing:
I add a new utility class for minimum width to a component:
// components/ExampleComponent.tsx
export default function ExampleComponent() {
  return (
    <div className="min-w-full">
      This div should have a minimum width of 100%.
    </div>
  );
}

After adding the min-w-full class, I don't see the changes reflected until I perform the following steps:

Stop the development server
Delete the .next folder
Restart the development server: npm run dev

Here's my tailwind.config.js:
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */

module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./app/**/*.{ts,tsx}",
    "./app/_components/**/*ts,tsx}",
    "./**/*.{ts,tsx}",
  ],
  mode: "jit",
  theme: {
    container: {
      center: true,
      padding: "2rem",
      screens: {
        "2xl": "1450px",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [require("tailwindcss-animate")],
};

I have also tried to add mode: "jit
or running this command:
TAILWIND_MODE=watch next dev
but it did nothing..

Try updating the content array in the tailwind.config.js file with this:
content: ['./pages/**/*.{ts,tsx}', './components/**/*.{ts,tsx}','./app/**/*.{ts,tsx}', './src/**/*.{ts,tsx}']

I already have it in my config file, unfortunately, it didn't work

Did you use this exact code I shared or you mean the same one that's in the question?

I have tried the code that you have shared (before, when started to research on the problem)
e.g.
content: ["./pages//*.{ts,tsx}",
"./components//*.{ts,tsx}", etc..]
